# UITableView always displays basic cell instead of custom cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode9

I spent hours of trying to fix this, but my simple app still displays the basic cell type instead of my prototype cell. I'm aware of using the identifier and registering after loading up the view, but it still displays the basic cells with just one label.

Here is my code so far:

My prototype is using this UITableViewCell:

```
class CoinTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var coinIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var holdings: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

UITableViewController:

```
class CoinTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var coins = ["Coin1","Coin2","Coin3"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.tableView.register(CoinTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "currency_cell")
   }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return coins.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell:CoinTableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currency_cell", for: indexPath) as! CoinTableViewCell
       let coinName = coins[indexPath.row]
       cell.coinTitleLabel?.text = coinName
       return cell!

   }
}
```

[image: Setting the cell identifier]

[image: Screenshot from iPhone Simulator]

I would be so grateful if someone is able the help me out with this!

Comment: `let cell:CoinTableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currency_cell", for: indexPath) as! CoinTableViewCell` would crash if it was not `CoinTableViewCell`.. there is an error somewhere else..

Comment: If you are using a storyboard then you don't need to register the cell reuse identifier. I agree, you have some other issue here. Have you set the delegate and data source for your table view?

Comment: Yes, I've done this by including self.tableView.delegate = self and self.tableView.dataSource = self into the viewDidLoad(). I omitted these lines for better readability here.

Comment: Have you set constraints on your cell so that the content is displayed? Have you set breakpoints to verify that your `numberOfRow` function is being called?  How are you creating this view controller?  Is it the initial view controller in the storyboard? What happens if you take the conditional unwrap off `cell.coinTitkeLabel.text` in cell for row?; have you linked the IBOutlets between your prototype cell and your cell class?

Comment: pera found the bug. I've replaced my prototype with a plain one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your custom cell directly on the tableview in the storyboard, right ?
If this is the case then you don't need to register the cell in your `viewDidLoad` as the storyboard takes care of that. You just deque it and it's good to go.

If you register it manually you just override what the storyboard did and end up getting a regular cell as the cell gets instantiated from the code instead of getting instantiated from the storyboard.

Cheers

Comment: You were right! Removing the registration does actually fix my problem. Thank you